# Jupyter notebook launch from shortcut

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

i was using Anacondas, but decided to switch to miniconda3 package (for weight reduction)
so i installed  miniconda3 package, and later jupyter notebook.
the problem is: i need everytime run "Anaconda Prompt (miniconda3)" with "jupyter notebook" to start notebook.

Is there any way to launch Jupyter Notebook with shortcut, same (or similar) to Anacondas distro?

Ps i am on windows OS

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can create a shortcut pointing to the following path:

```
%PY_HOME%\python.exe %PY_HOME%\cwp.py %PY_HOME% %PY_HOME%\python.exe -m jupyter notebook
```

Where `%PY_HOME%` is my environment variable pointing to the Anaconda folder (example: `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`). It's useful to use the environment variable because you may run out of characters.

If you want to run a especific environment:

```
%PY_HOME%\python.exe %PY_HOME%\cwp.py %PY_HOME%\envs\myenvironment %PY_HOME%\envs\myenvironment\python.exe -m jupyter notebook
```